# Why is it redundant to cast both arguments of a function call in Java if the function parameters are the same type?

Tags: java, overloading, redundancy

I am curious to know how casting works in function calls. I have two overloads of a specific function in my class called `execute`. The first overload is the base implementation and accepts `double` type parameters. The second overload accepts `int` type parameters. The second overload also calls the base overload and does so by casting the parameters to `double`.

The base implementation looks like this:

```
public double execute(double leftVal, double rightVal) throws IOException {
    ...
    return solution;
}
```

and the overloaded version looks like this:

```
public int execute(int leftVal, int rightVal) throws IOException {
    return (int) execute((double) leftVal, (double) rightVal);
}
```

Why is the above, specifically the `(double) leftVal, (double) rightVal` part, a redundancy and why does it work with one of the casts removed? The call to the first overload works no matter which order the casting is in. Both `execute(leftVal, (double)rightVal)` and `execute((double) leftVal, rightVal)` execute normally, producing no errors. I have always thought Java was very strict on explicitly identifying types. I would expect some warning or error that there isn't a function that exists to accept call like `execute(double, int)`. I have an idea, though, that the first cast helps the compiler determine which overload to choose so the second cast is implicit. Maybe because the types are primitive easily cast-able? Also mini-question, are both functions called overloads or is every definition after the first an overload of the original?

Comment: Who told you the casts are redundant? They are not if you actually want the int method to call the double method.

Comment: @Sweeper The IDE I was using. I usually ignore any syntax insights it offers if they're _sugary_, but this was stuck out because it doesn't sound like it should work.

Comment: Oh, did you mean _one_ of the casts were redundant? You can remove one of the casts, but not both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the above, specifically the (double) leftVal, (double) rightVal part, a redundancy?

the cast you made above is necessary for you to explicitly state that you want to call that base-level, overloaded function. Otherwise, the code will just assume you want to recurse in that same method. So yes, you are right in saying "the first cast helps the compiler determine which overload to choose"

> So the second cast is implicit. Maybe because the types are primitive easily cast-able?

So if you are going from a primitive type that requires a smaller amount of bits (`int` is 32 bits) to a primitive type that accommodates a larger amount of bits (`double` is 64 bits), Java knows to do this at runtime. However, if you go from a `double` (64 bit) to an `int` (32 bit), you as a developer **need to explicitly cast since you can run into information loss here**. This is why that (int) cast is necessary on the return; you are going from a `double` to an `int` which can be lossy.

**Some Example Code:**

```
public class Test {

    public int intMethod(int intArg) {
        return intArg;
    }

    public long longMethod(long longArg) {
        // will NOT compile, since we didn't explicitly cast to narrower int type (potentially lossy)
        return intMethod(longArg);
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {

    public int intMethod(int intArg) {
        return intArg;
    }

    public long longMethod(long longArg) {
        // WILL compile, since we explicitly cast to narrower int type. Also note we do not need to cast result, since result is going from int --> long, which is not lossy
        return intMethod((int) longArg); 
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {

    public int intMethod(int intArg) {
        // WILL compile. don't need to specify arg since its not lossy, but we do specify return type since its lossy
        return (int) longMethod(intArg);
    }

    public long longMethod(long longArg) {
        return 3L;
    }
}
```

> I have always thought Java was very strict on explicitly identifying types

Primitives are a much more nuanced feature of the Java language. I think by types, you're implicitly referring to `Object`'s in Java. You are right that Java is much more strict with respect to Object-casting. If we take the above example and use `Long` and `Integer` objects, they won't compile, and will flag a warning `Cannot case java.lang.Long to java.lang.Integer`;

**Examples that Won't Compile due to Invalid Casting**

```
public class Test {

    public Integer intMethod(Integer intArg) {
        return intArg;
    }

    public Long longMethod(Long longArg) {
        return intMethod((Integer) longArg);
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {

    public Integer intMethod(Integer intArg) {
        return longMethod((Long) intArg);
    }

    public Long longMethod(Long longArg) {
        return 3L;
    }
}
```

ps: it's standard to refer to all functions w/ the same method name as overloaded; not common to refer to one method as the "base" and say the rest overload that method

Comment: Setting this as the accepted answer because it does a better job explaining why widening and narrowing primitive conversions are distinguished. Also, you pointed out the nuance of primitives in Java opposed to Object types. And you answered all of my questions in a very concise way. Thank you this explains a lot, actually. And the ps tidbit is much appreciated, lol.

Answer (score 6):

Removing either one of the casts will still work, because in an invocation context, a widening primitive conversion is permitted. So no, Java not as strict about types as you thought :)

As per the Java Language Specification [§5.3 Invocation Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)

> Invocation contexts allow an argument value in a method or constructor
>   invocation (§8.8.7.1, §15.9, §15.12) to be assigned to a corresponding
>   formal parameter.
>
> Strict invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)

A "widening primitive conversion" is... ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2))

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - `byte` to `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `short` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `char` to `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `int` to `long`, `float`, or `double`
> - `long` to `float` or `double`
> - `float` to `double`

`int` to `double` is one of the above conversions, and is therefore permitted when you call a method. On the other hand, `double` to `int` is a narrowing primitive conversion, which is not allowed in an invocation context. This explains why the `(double, double)` method is *unambiguously* called.

Comment: Oh, this makes a lot of sense. So, I'm assuming if I did it in the reverse order, I would not get the same behavior and have to explicitly cast each double to an int type.

Comment: @kohai If by "reverse order" you mean to make the `(double, double)` method call the `(int, int)` method, then yes you are right.

Answer (score -1):

You can understand that the nature of overloading is early binding, and the compiler verifies that the binding is a suitable function in the compiler.